# Change node.js Buffer(BASE64) to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Could you help me please, I had a program which written with Node.js. It has this part:

```
    var b = new Buffer(text, 'base64');
    var s = b.toString('hex');
```

Do you have any idea, how could I this code change to jQuery?
I tried this, but It is not give a good values:

```
var text = "ACfACRv7aEcAAAAAAAD//w=="; //23,31 was the value
var b = atob(text);
console.log(b);
var s = b.toString('hex');
console.log(s);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert Base64 into hex :

> var base64Image = 'MjMsMzE=';
>
> console.log(convertToHex(base64Image));
>
> function convertToHex(base64) {
>
> ```
> var hex = '';
> for(var i=0;i<base64.length;i++) {
>     hex += ''+base64.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
> }
> return hex;
> ```
>
> }